# Duplicate the page.main.title

Tags: product, frontend

I wanted to duplicate the "page.main.title" element on the product pages, so I added this block to my catalog_product_view.ml

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="title.additional2" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml">
   <arguments>
      <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
      <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
   </arguments>
</block>
```

I want to add this block because I moved "page.main.title" elsewhere on the page.

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="page.top" before="breadcrumbs" />
```

"page.main.title" displays the product name, but my new block (title.additional2) displays the content of the meta title and I don't understand why?

Thanks in advance if anyone can explain this result to me.
Good day

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of your phtml calling this class **Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title.php** in which phtml using the **getPageHeading** function, This function gives title of page only on the first time rendering and on second time it's give page title as empty which result to show the page meta title.

**For Override this we need to be follow the below steps :**

Create/Update the **catalog_product_view.xml** in your module or your theme. Add the lines in the file **{vendor_module}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="title.additional2" template="Vendor_Module::html/title2.phtml"/>
```

Create your custom block in your Module
**{vendor_module}/Block/Productdata.php**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\Module\Block;

class Productdata extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

Create a phtml file in   **{vendor_module}/view/frontend/templates/html/title2.phtml**
and add the below code in it

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$product= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Productdata');



$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$titleHtml = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    $titleHtml = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" '
        . $block->getAddBaseAttribute()
        . '>'
        . $product->getCurrentProduct()->getName()
        . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($titleHtml) : ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper testing<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($cssClass) ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()) : ?> id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getId()) ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) : ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $titleHtml ?>
    </h1>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand your answer, it doesn't answer my question?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please review and let me know if issue still exists.